# Comparing beta coefficients from a GLMM

Tags: logistic, statistical-significance, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, interaction

I have a logistic mixed-effects model with multiple predictors:

```
y ~ (x1 + x2 + x3)*x4 + x5 + (x1 + x2 + x3 | id), family = "binomial"
```

I would like to know whether the interaction between, let's say, x1 and x4 (both continuous variables), is statistically significantly different from the interaction between x2 (also continuous) and x4. Is it possible to do so? What methods should I use?

Notes based on EdM's comment: x1 and x2 represent differences between two options based on a certain aspect of each option. To make this more concrete, let's say (as a toy example) that you are choosing between apples and oranges. y is whether you choose apples (0) or oranges (1). x1 could be the difference (oranges-apples) in calories between apples and oranges. x2 could be the difference in tastiness between oranges and apples. Your choice of what to eat will depend on both x1 and x2. However, the two may interact with x4 - let's say that x4 is time of the year. The later in the year, the stronger/weaker the effects of x1 and x2 may be. I want to know whether the interaction between x1 and x4 is different than that between x2 and x4. x1 and x2 are roughly on the scale, because they are both divided by their own standard deviation. However, the values are not exactly z-scored because the 0-value is meaningful, so I did not center them.

Thanks!

Comment: check out "contrasts".

Comment: Please look at the second paragraph of [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/272285/28500). This comparison _might_ make sense if `x1` and `x2` are effectively on the same scale, but otherwise such comparison is tricky. It would help if you could edit the question to provide more details about the model, the variables involved, and what you hope to gain from comparing the interactions. Please provide such extra information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: @EdM please let me know if this helps

Comment: @JohnMadden could you expand?

Comment: for background: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_(statistics) to do it in R: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/contrast/vignettes/contrast.html

Comment: thanks @JohnMadden! Looks like that would work well for categorical variables, but not so much for continuous ones. Am I missing something?

Comment: @gimi You sure are ;) no need for categorical variables for contrasts to work; see Ed's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the predictors `x1` and `x2` are on the same scale, one approach would be to examine whether the interaction-coefficient estimates $\beta_{x_1 :x_4}$ and $\beta_{x_2 :x_4}$ can be distinguished statistically. The null hypothesis would be that $\beta_{x_1 :x_4}-\beta_{x_2 :x_4}=0$. A linear combination of variables that equals 0 is called a [contrast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_(statistics)) in statistics.

To test that hypothesis you need to estimate the standard error of that difference. For that you need to use the formula for the variance of a [weighted sum of correlated variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_variables). In this case:

$$\text{Var}(\beta_{x_1 :x_4}-\beta_{x_2 :x_4})= \text{Var}(\beta_{x_1 :x_4}) + \text{Var}(\beta_{x_2 :x_4})-2\text{Cov}(\beta_{x_1 :x_4},\beta_{x_2 :x_4})$$

The variances and covariance on the right side of the equation are found in the coefficient variance-covariance matrix provided by the model. Take the square root of the result for the standard error, `SE`. With a generalized linear model the coefficient estimates have an asymptotic multivariate normal distribution, so you use a *z*-statistic $(\beta_{x_1 :x_4}-\beta_{x_2 :x_4})/\text{SE}$ to evaluate whether the difference in coefficients is statistically different from 0.

There are software tools that can make this easier and less error-prone, particularly for more complicated comparisons. [This page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/111566/28500) illustrates the `linearHypothesis()` function of the R [`car` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=car).

You should be very careful in the case of your model, however. The above will only evaluate the fixed-effect interactions, while you have random slopes involving those variables. It also assumes that `x3` is constant. The usefulness of the comparison also depends on having both `x1` and `x2` on the same scale.

It might be more informative to illustrate predictions from the model under specific scenarios. See the help page for `predict.merMod()` in the [`lme4` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=lme4). If you are going to include random effects in your predictions, also see the `bootMer()` help page.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain why the assumption that x3 is constant is necessary, and what you mean by that?

Comment: @gimi `x3` is also in an interaction with `x4`. You say in part: "let's say that x4 is time of the year. The later in the year, the stronger/weaker the effects of x1 and x2 may be." If you are comparing multiple scenarios (e.g., a range values of `x1` against a range of values of `x2` at a set of `x4` values), then the value of `x3` must be the same in all comparisons for the $\beta_{x_1 :x_4}$ and $\beta_{x_2 :x_4}$ coefficients to capture the role of `x4` totally. If $x_3$ varies, you have to add in the contribution from $\beta_{x_3 :x_4} x_3 x_4$ for valid prediction.

Comment: thanks again! How do you do that in r with car::linearHypothesis? So far I have car::linearHypothesis(model, c("x1:x4 = x2:x4")) but I'm not sure how to account for x3

Comment: @gimi if `x3` is constant then you don't have to account for it and you are done. If you want to compare scenarios with different values of the predictors, see the functions in the last paragraph of the answer.